# Receiving an error when trying to install n

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm getting the following error when trying to install n, after getting a previous error saying that I need to upgrade my node to run npm commands.

The error is as follows:

```
PS C:\new-project> npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@7.3.0: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Npm version

```
PS C:\new-project> npm -v
6.9.0
```

Node version

```
PS C:\new-project> node -v
v12.5.0
```

Comment: You're trying to install [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n), not nvm. And the error seems clear: it doesn't support Windows https://www.npmjs.com/package/n#supported-platforms.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the nvm project is only for linux and macos, and cannot be installed in windows.
But there is an alternative which is not clone but recommend nodejs version manager. Here is the [link](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)